# AWS AppSync + React-Apollo Query/useQuery raising exception this.currentObservable.query.getCurrentResult is not a function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm new to GraphQL/Apollo thing and I'm having a hard time to setup it with a React application.

I have a React component that loads a list from a GraphQL API built using Amplify/AppSync.

If I call manually to fetch the items, i.e:

```
    const videosData = await client.query({
      query: gql(queries.listVideos)
    });
    const videosItems = videosData.data.listVideos.items;
    setVideosData(videosItems);
```

Works like a charm.
However, if I try to use Apollo Query component or useQuery hook, it raises the following error:

> TypeError: this.currentObservable.query.getCurrentResult is not a
>   function

If I just add the line to fetch the query using a hook it already gives me this error

the hook call:

```
const {loading, error, data, refetch} = useQuery(gql(queries.listVideos));
```

The called function raising the issue:

```
QueryData.getQueryResult
node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.esm.js:325
  322 |     called: true
  323 |   });
  324 | } else {
> 325 |   var currentResult = this.currentObservable.query.getCurrentResult();
      | ^  326 |   var loading = currentResult.loading,
  327 |       partial = currentResult.partial,
  328 |       networkStatus = currentResult.networkStatus,
```

The exact same problem happens if I use the `<Query>` component

Packages versions:

> ```
> "aws-amplify": "^1.1.30",
> "aws-amplify-react": "^2.3.10",
> "aws-appsync": "^1.8.1",
> "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
> "react-apollo": "^3.0.1",
> ```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you found any solutions?

Comment: @BrianMcDonough Not yet... tbh I ended up with so many issues for setup this serverless graphql api and little support that I'm thinking about getting back to the good and old REST server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in other answer the problem is because `aws-appsync` is relying in an previous version `apollo-client`. 
Using resolutions is not the "cleaner" way to solve this problem as you're fixing a dependency version which is not fully compatible with this library.

I strongly recommend you to create a custom apollo client for AWS AppSync this way:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import { createAuthLink } from 'aws-appsync-auth-link';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { AppSyncConfig } from '.aws-exports';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";

const url = AppSyncConfig.graphqlEndpoint;
const region = AppSyncConfig.region;
const auth = {
  type: AppSyncConfig.authenticationType,
  apiKey: AppSyncConfig.apiKey
};
const link = ApolloLink.from([
   createAuthLink({ url, region, auth }), 
   createHttpLink({ uri: url })
]);
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

const WithProvider = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
)

export default WithProvider
```

I also created a more detailed post on [medium](https://medium.com/@guillac124/create-your-custom-apollo-client-for-aws-appsync-to-use-hooks-2d5cbce29db5)

Comment: This works, thanks!!! I used with ```jwtToken``` auth (Cognito). Maybe add in your answer the missing ```import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";```

Comment: Glad it worked for you @sigmus. I noticed and fixed it on my post but I forgot to do the same here, thanks!

Comment: @GuilleAcosta Great solution thanks. Just a quick question, how to make it work with subscriptions?

Comment: @SatvikDaga are you having issues to subscribe? which error are you getting? did you follow these steps? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/

Comment: @GuilleAcosta I followed the steps but got an error. Using a createSubscriptionHandshakeLink solved it

Comment: Does this also support offline support of mutations?

Answer (score 9):

If you add:

```
"resolutions": {
  "apollo-client": "2.6.3"
}
```

In your `package.json` and reinstall it should work.

You might see this warning:

```
Resolution field "apollo-client@2.6.3" is incompatible with requested version "apollo-client@2.4.6"
```

it is because Appsync is relying on a old version of react-apollo, but I've found that is working fine.

You could follow [this issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/450) which hopefully will be resolved soon and we'll not need to do this anymore.

Comment: This doesn't work. The issue referenced in the answer is still open and vividly debated.